# Is there PvP gear for characters under the level cap?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've been rockin' some Huttball matches, accruing a fat stack of Warzone Commendations.

Now, I want to spend them -- but the only vendors I've been able to find exclusively cater to max level items.

Are there any purchasable PvP items usable before reaching the max level?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The vendors called "PvP Armor" sell some level 20 and 40 equipment:

[image: PvP Armor vendor with level 20 item]

Then there is a "PvP Weapons" vendor, who sells weapons starting from level 14:

[image: PvP Weapons vendor with level 20 weapon]

And finally, "PvP Items" vendor sells lockboxes from level 10 up.

I'm not sure I would call them "PvP gear", though, since they don't seem to increase Expertise (the PvP-specific stat).

All this is from Imperial Fleet, but I assume Republic Fleet (and possibly Dromund Kass and Coruscant) are the same.

Answer (score 4):

[Yes there are.](http://www.torhead.com/item/7RcvnS0#currency-for;sort:minlevel,-basequality)

There are Gloves, Belts, and Implants available at level 20, and Belts and Earpieces at level 40.

You can buy these from your class specific PVP Vendor at the Fleet, or on Dromund Kaas/Coruscant.

Comment: The vendors Torhead lists as having those items... don't have those items. (Though I'd love a screenshot to prove me wrong). Simply put, where's the vendor?